# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery

This is my javascript function am calling on a page:

```
<script>
    $.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
        this.tabs();
        this.dialog({ 'minWidth': 300, 'minHeight': 300, 'draggable': true, 'autoOpen': false, 'resizable': false, });
        var $dialog = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');
        this.find('.ui-icon-closethick').append($('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')).css('position', 'static');
        $dialog.find('.ui-draggable-handle').append($('.ui-tabs-nav').removeClass().addClass('ui-tabs-nav')).addClass('ui-tabs');
        $dialog.find('.ui-dialog-title').remove();
    }
    $('#xxx').tabbedDialog();

    $('a#show').click(function () {
        if ($('#xxx').dialog("isOpen")) {
            $('#xxx').dialog('close');
        }
        else {
            $('#xxx').dialog('open');
        }
    });
</script>
```

jQuery dialog is conflicting with this script that is global to my template at this point when I try to open the dialog box and this is the script defined in the other javascript file attached to my template:

```
this.$dialog.on('mousedown.dismiss.bs.modal', function () {
      that.$element.one('mouseup.dismiss.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(that.$element)) that.ignoreBackdropClick = true
      })
    })
```

I have tried commenting the line of code disturbing the dialog but it distorts the other parts of my project. please how can I resolve this dialog conflict
Kindly assist!

Comment: create a demo with both plugins installed that replicates problem. Might have to rename one of the `$.fn` methods

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, `this.$dialog` and `jQuery.fn.dialog` has nothing to do with each other, you'd have to actually overwrite the prototyped method on the jQuery instance. You're sure the issue isn't just that you didn't load jQuery UI.

Comment: Hi adeneo, which jQuery.fn.dialog are you referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve my problem after much trying. I added this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//functions here
this.tabs();
$.noConflict(true);
.....
});
```

And the conflict was resolved.